# How to run a GPU program over SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gpu, x-server

I'm using Intel QSV accelerating, and the program runs well on a local Ubuntu desktop. When I run the program on a remote machine(the same os, with no monitor connnected) via ssh, it cannot find gpu device. And if I call "vainfo", it prompts

```
error: can't connect to X server!
error: failed to initialize display
```

I have forwarding X already, xhost does not help. The problem is iHD on the host is not initialized.
How could I enable Ubuntu's GPU support over SSH, without a monitor connected.

Comment: It currently is unclear which software you are asking about and what command you run exactly. Please edit your question with the additional information

Comment: I can see two solutions : (1) [Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/a/463000/963426), (2) Using x11vnc, see [Ubuntu Headless VNC VESA 800×600 Fix](https://web.archive.org/web/20150912064745/http://blog.mediafederation.com:80/andy-hawkins/ubuntu-headless-vnc-vesa-800x600-fix/). Would one of them answer your problem?

Comment: the command which prompts the error info is "vainfo", it detects the intel gpu. It doesn't matter running QSV in which software, the problem is GPU module on the host is not loaded when logon over ssh. @mashuptwice

Comment: Seems there are many version of virtual monitors, and most are incompatiable with latest os. I will try using a dummy connector. @harrymc

Comment: The GPU module isn't loaded at logon time anyway, it's loaded during system boot. The problem is likely that your tools assume the X server is on the same system as the accel GPU, which won't be the case when X-forwarding... that said, vainfo shouldn't _need_ X, it should just directly talk to the render node at `/dev/dri/renderD*`. Can you check whether your SSH logon has permissions to access those device nodes?

Comment: @PasserbyD - Were you able to get this to work? If I start my LLM (dual GPU bound model) locally, the model loads into GPU. If I start it remotely, it loads into CPU, although GPUs are recognised.